# How to drag and drop a button inside a table in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UpdateTableWebForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="SocietyWebApp.Views.UpdateTableWebForm" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <asp:Table ID="EditTable" runat="server"  CellPadding="5" Font-Names="Times New Roman">
          <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>Flat no.: </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
              <asp:TextBox ID="FlatNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
              <asp:Button ID="SearchByNoButton" runat="server" Text="Search" onClick="SearchByNoButtonClicked" />
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage=" * Flat no. is required" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="FlatNo" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage=" * must be a no." ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="FlatNo" ValidationExpression="[0-9]*" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </asp:TableCell>
          </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can not drag'n'drop. Only manual coding in asp.net works to add buttons or text boxes inside the table in an aspx page. Can anyone tell how to drag'n'drop. Also generating a button click event by double clicking doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot perform these actions in the designer of your Visual Studio (or other like it) or you cannot drag and drop a button on the web page the code generates?

Answer (score 0):

Repair your visual studio software !!! I hope it will works for u !!!

Run your visual studio CD or exe. File which will provide options to repair.